# Adding Authorization Header is not working - Angular 5

Tags: angular, interceptor

I drew up an Interceptor in order to send an Authorization token in every HTTP Request, but it seems not to be working. I have searched every where and it seems to be right, would you guys happen to know if I am missing something here? Thanks in advance, down below is my code

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public authContext: AuthContextService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authContext.getEncodedToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Just so you guys know, the application is passing through the interceptor as planned, the weird thing is that afterwards, the header is not there

Comment: Do you happen to have a Django backend and are using safari or Firefox? And if not; did you provide the interceptor in app.module?

Comment: @baao, my Backend is built using Spring Boot and I am running the application on Chrome. As for the declaration, I did declare it on app.module. I debugged it and it is passing correctly through the Interceptor and the token is there, the thing is: Weirdly it is not being added on the request afterwards. Do you think my method is wrong? Thank u

Comment: I had a similar problem today, but w Django which was doing a redirect because of a missing trailing slash, removing the headers; no idea if that has something to do with your problem though. From what I see here everything looks fine. What exactly do you mean with “declared” it in app.module? It needs to be in the Providers array, as HttpInterceptor

Comment: @NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],

Comment: Your interceptor is named as AuthInterceptor not MyInterceptor as you have mentioned in providers

Comment: The interceptor works fine! I noticed something weird: As I debugged the code, the variable request has an attribute called 'lazyUpdate', in this particular attribute, my token appears whereas in the attributes 'headers' it does't. It is blowing my mind –

Answer (score 0):

Either change the useClass to AuthInterceptor or refactor the AuthInterceptor class to MyInterceptor. You have provided different names in both places.
If you are using multiple interceptors:

```
providers: [
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyInterceptor, multi: true },
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor , multi: true }
],
```

Comment: The interceptor works fine! I noticed something weird: As I debugged the code, the variable request has an attribute called 'lazyUpdate', in this particular attribute, my  token appears whereas in the attributes 'headers' it does't. It is blowing my mind